# Mocha test express async middleware done not working

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I'm trying to test an async middleware auth function using the done function of Mocha. However, it seems that the test completes before the done function is called in the async call. Isn't the test supposed to wait until the done callback is called?

The middlware:

```
const AuthMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const token = getToken(req)

    if (token === undefined) {
        res.status(401)
        next()
    }

    jwt.verify(token, getSigningKey, (err, decodedToken) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401)
            next()
        }
    })
}
```

My test:

```
describe("AuthMiddleware", () => {
    it("Should return 401 if token is expired", (done) => {
        const options = { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + expiredToken } }
        const req = mockReq(options) as Request
        const res = mockRes() as Response

        AuthMiddleware(req, res, done)
        expect(res.status).to.have.been.calledWith(401)
    }).timeout(10000)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating done() as next(). Done is used to end the test while next is used in your middle ware

```
describe("AuthMiddleware", () => {
it("Should return 401 if token is expired",async (done) => {
    const options = { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + expiredToken } }
    const req = mockReq(options) as Request
    const res = mockRes() as Response

    await AuthMiddleware(req, res, done)
    expect(res.status).to.have.been.calledWith(401)
}).timeout(10000)
```

})

Comment: I thought that was the default approach to using done in middleware. Do you have any suggestion as to how i apply done the right way in this scenario?

Comment: try out this modified code please. Async await is used when the function will take time to perform some operations and after that the rest of the code can use that data. Else the rest of code will give error as what is needs is not there which is the output of the function where await is applied.

Comment: I followed you suggestion, and wrapped the middleware logic in a promise that resolves in either of the two places before the next function calls. It works perfectly. Thank you.